# How to install PL/php on Potgresql with Windows?

Tags: php, windows, postgresql

I'm trying to install this on my PostgreSQL server to write procedures with PHP
https://public.commandprompt.com/documents/5
the docs looks great but the problem is they are for linux and my company only have access to a Windows Server.
Someone can tell me how to install PL/php on Windows please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you'd need to compile from source, probably with mingw or Visual Studio, and you;d need the PostgreSQL header files.

My recommendation is to avoid this addon for this language and wait for someone else to do it for you, or to get involved, build it for yourself, and then release your own Windows build as advertising for your business and an effort to reduce porting maintenance.